# Calling super.setter calls the getter for no apparent reason

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I have a base class ("Master") that implements a setter (let's call it "a").
There's another class that extends Master ("Extended") and overrides the "a" setter.

The getter for "a" returns a new instance of an object every time, and is also overridden in Extended class.

The overridden setter looks something like this:

```
override public function set a(value:Object):void
{
    doSomethingWithValue(value);
    super.a = value;
    doSometingExtraWithValue(value);
}
```

Now for the magic that happens: whenever the overridden setter is called, the moment the `super.a = value` is being executed, the overridden getter is being invoked for no reason whatsoever.

Why, is the question. There isn't any rule that says "call getter when setter is called", is there?

Comment: how does the Master setter looks like? Are you calling the getter in there?

Comment: Master's setter is just `_a = value`, no reference to the getter in any way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no hidden rules of that kind in As3.
There is two easy ways to find out what happen :

- Use a break point with flash Debugger (avaible on Flash Develop or Flash Builder exemple).
  Just add this break point in your getter so you will have the stacktrace and you can interact with it.
- add the following code in your getter, you'll have the stacktrace and you will find what triggered getter call :

  trace(new Error().getStackTrace());